# how to sort values of user inputs in textboxes and to be printed in labels?

Tags: c#

i have 5 conditions named a,b,c,d, and e. then i have 5 labels named 1,2,3,4,and 5 then i have 5 textbox which is used as user input to declare what they want to sort. example the user inputs in:

```
text box 1 = 5
text box 2 = 3
text box 3 = 1
text box 4 = 4 
text box 5 = 2
```

how to sort them from least to greatest; i mean i want my output to be arrange in least to greatest then show it to textboxes.

```
label 1 = 1;(which is txtbox3)
label 2 = 2;(which is txtbox5)
label 3 = 3;(which is txtbox2)
label 4 = 4;(which is txtbox4)
label 5 = 5;(which is txtbox1)
```

and how to code if the first label has a value then the second one to be printed will be printed in label 2.

Comment: Can you demonstrate that you put in some effort?  What have you tried, and why didn't it work?

Comment: _"i have 5 conditions named a,b,c,d"_ you havent shown or used these conditions, so it's not clear in what way they are relevant. In general it's very hard to understand this question and the reason is not your english.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the values in a list and sort the list

```
        string A = "3";
        string B = "6";
        string C = "1";
        string D = "2";
        string E = "7";

        List<string> Vali = new List<string>() { A, B, C, D, E };
        Vali.Sort();

        Label1.Text = Vali[0];
        Label2.Text = Vali[1];
        // ...
```

It was mentioned that values greater than 9 (10, 11) are not sorted the way we want as string, so basically I convert them to int and back

```
        string a = "4";
        int A = Convert.ToInt32(a);
        int B = 7;
        int C = 10;
        int D = 4;
        int E = 1;

        List<int> Vali = new List<int>() { A, B, C, D, E };
        Vali.Sort();
        Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(Vali[0]);
        Label2.Text = Convert.ToString(Vali[1]);
```

Comment: What will be the output if `E` is `10`??

Comment: Just checked: It is handled as 1 0 and not 10. Alternative, convert your strings to int and use a List<int>, I guarantee this will work ;)

Comment: Then you need to modify your answer accordingly

Comment: Did it the moment you mentioned it